# CQL request composition

Tags: ndepend, cql

Is it possible to compose requests in CQL ?

I would like to write something like:

SELECT TYPES FROM ASSEMBLIES "myassemblie" WHERE
IsUsing SELECT METHODS FROM ASSEMBLIES "myotherassemblie" WHERE IsStatic

Thanks,
Vans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NDepend team is proud to finally provides an elegant answer to this question :)  Thanks to the new NDepend v4 [Code Query LINQ (CQLinq) feature](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL), what you are asking for can be written for example like:

```
let staticMethods = Application.Assemblies.WithName("nunit.core")
                    .ChildMethods().Where(m => m.IsStatic)

from t in Application.Assemblies.WithName("nunit.util")
          .ChildTypes().UsingAny(staticMethods )

let staticMethodsUsed = staticMethods.UsedBy(t)
select new { t, staticMethodsUsed  }
```

There are many other ways to write such query, but this way is certainly the most concise and optimized one (*the top-right panel tells it is executed in 4ms*):

[image: Code Query Composition through CQLinq]